# What are the frames at the ends of benches called?

Tags: wood, furniture

Even though I’m trying to build more stuff on my own, I’m DIY-challenged.

So today I saw these [2x4 chair ends](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BDH8RE).

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BDH8RE)*</sup>

I liked the overall idea, but I didn’t like the material these chair ends were made from. They’re made from resin and they looked cheap.

I guess my question is: what are these called and does this exist in another material besides plastic?

Comment: you could paint them, then they would look a lot better. i've seen metal ones too, but not as a kit w/o wood.

Comment: that is not a chair ... google `park bench ends`

Comment: Isn't the answer right in the Amazon listing? "Bench ends" yields a huge number of search results.

Comment: Contrarian voice: I've had bench thingies like that for a few years, and they're perfectly durable. Aesthetics is up to you, of course.

Comment: You might as well paint them, otherwise UV light will eat them after a few years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is the modern soulless crappy plastic injection molded version and the old classy cast iron bench ends.

Do a search for cast iron bench ends and you will find a world of benches and bench ends from basic to elaborate and ornate.

Go out a find a pair Paint them black and ad some oak slats, your DIY street cred will go up considerably.

[search result image page](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cast%20iron%20bench%20ends&t=ffsb&atb=v36-1&ia=images)

Comment: Oak slats - yes. Anything furniture made with pine 2 x 4s will look like a 12 year old made it.

Answer (score 1):

Park bench is what we call them , I have one made of cast iron, I have seen them made out of tube steel and concrete also. As many plastic chairs as I have seen broken I would want the cast iron or tube steel , the concrete ones were super heavy.